# Azure SQL server IN statement not throwing error

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

When I write a sql statement containing an in clause, if the column in the in statement does not exist it does not throw an error, but just ignores the in statement and returns a resultset.

Query below will return all rows from T1

```
SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE Id IN(SELECT Id FROM T2)
```

Is that the correct behaviour for SQL Azure?
My local MS SQL server throws an error saying the column does not exist.

Comment: As mentioned in below answer,this is not possible.if you are able to repro,you should file a bug with CSS

Comment: Just tested this on my v12 SQL Azure database and cannot reproduce your issue. Can you please add information about both tables schemas and the exact query you are running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior, same as in Sql Server. Basically, if a column is referenced in a subquery that does not exist in the table referenced by the subquery's FROM clause, but exists in a table referenced by the outer query's FROM clause, the query executes without error. SQL Server implicitly qualifies the column in the subquery with the table name in the outer query.
This is documented here: 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178050(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Frankly, what you are describing is impossible. If the column inside the IN statement doesn't exist, Azure will throw an exception. A result set cannot possibly be returned. Currently there is very little difference between the way SQL Server executes a query and the way Azure v12 does. Each may generate a different execution plan, but essentially there is very little difference between the two.

Comment: I know it should be, but I can reproduce it. If the table inside the IN statement does not have an column named Id and you select that, it ignores the IN statement unless the table in the IN statement does not have any rows, then the resultset will be empty.

Comment: Well, the only thing that can explain it is the schema's of the two tables are not identical.